# wp_get_archives() - Get CSS selector for current month

Tags: css, wp-get-archives

I'm looking for how to get a class in the wp_get_archives functions to get the current month (when we are in a month archive) just like when we call wp_list_categories, the current category has a ".current-cat" selector for CSS or when we call wp_list_pages we have a '.current_page_item' selector.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This function was created with the great help of Joshua Abenazer. Thanks! Basically, if is a monthly archive, go and get the current month watched, and add a class on the li. Worked great.

```
function wpse_62509_current_month_selector( $link_html ) {
    if (is_month()){
        $current_month = get_the_date("F Y");
        if ( preg_match('/'.$current_month.'/i', $link_html ) )
            $link_html = preg_replace('/<li>/i', '<li class="current-month">', $link_html );
    }
    return $link_html;
}

add_filter( 'get_archives_link', 'wpse_62509_current_month_selector' );
```

Answer (score 4):

Put the following function in your `functions.php`

```
function wpse_62509_current_month_selector( $link_html ) {
    $current_month = date("F Y");
    if ( preg_match('/'.$current_month.'/i', $link_html ) )
        $link_html = preg_replace('/<li>/i', '<li class="current-month">', $link_html );
    return $link_html;
}
```

And then add the following line just before calling `wp_get_archives()`

```
add_filter( 'get_archives_link', 'wpse_62509_current_month_selector' );
```

You might also want to remove the filter after calling `wp_get_archives()` so that it doesn't mess with other `wp_get_archives()` or `get_archives_link()` function calls.

```
remove_filter( 'get_archives_link', 'wpse_62509_current_month_selector' );
```

Comment: Youre on the right track, but what I'm asking is to find the current month of the archives. Maybe I'll try taking it from the URL (www.example.com/2012/08/) to get the values you use.

Comment: Well after just a few modifications, that code worked. Thanks! The corrected code is in my answer below.

Comment: The `remove_filter()` for some reason did not work for me. If I removed it, it worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

As of WordPress 5.3, `<a>` elements generated by wp_get_archives ([etc](https://make.wordpress.org/core/2019/09/23/core-widgets-new-aria-current-attribute-in-wordpress-5-3/)) for links to the current page have the attribute `aria-current="page"` added to them. If you just want to style the current page link differently, you can now target this with CSS, assuming you are happy for the styles to all be on the `<a>`:

```
a[aria-current="page"] {
color: red;
}
```

…or even just:

```
a[aria-current] {
color: red;
}
```